# Bring Live Drupal site to Local Host

Tags: drupal, url, localhost, live

I've made a local version of my companies live website. My problem is that none of the links work and I can't sign into the admin control panel. I think it has something to do with clean-urls module. Any Ideas? The error I'm getting is url request was not found on this server.

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding the error (e.g. is it a PHP error? Drupal error?) and how the error is displayed? Are you able to see/access any parts of the website (even if they are distorted)? Any additional errors?

Comment: ALl I know is that the sites links aren't working locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made a full copy including the database, you must clear all caches, e.g. directly in the database, or using the [Devel-Module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). If no other settings have changed in the .htaccess, and there is no fixed url given in the settings.php (the $base_url), it should work.

Comment: There is no fixed Url setting and I haven't changed anything in the .htaccess file. How could I Clear all cashes in the db locally?

Comment: just truncate all tables beginning with cache_

Comment: Ok, thank you. The url seem to work when I place a ?q= infront